# mysql get count(column) if first select query return no result

Tags: sql, mysql, not-exists

I want to execute 2nd query if first query return no result. I want to get those id age > 20. If no result, want to get number of id with age < 20.

In table:

```
   id   name   gender   age
    1   'Ryan'  'M'     30
    2  'Joanna' 'F'     10
```

query

```
(SELECT id FROM students WHERE age > 20
ORDER BY id desc limit 1)

UNION ALL

SELECT count(id) FROM students WHERE age < 20 AND 
NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM students WHERE age > 20  ORDER BY id desc limit 1)
```

result :

```
   id 
    1 
    0
```

It should return 1 only but return 1 and 0.

If change ryan age to 10, it return 2 which is correct.

Link :[query](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/EmkYr1MWGVa)

Comment: `SELECT COUNT()` returns a row ALWAYS. Use `SELECT cnt FROM (SELECT COUNT(id) AS cnt ..) AS x WHERE NOT EXISTS (..)`.

Comment: Do you really want to get a list of id's in one case and a single count in the other? Or is your description incorrect and you want to get a list or a count in both cases?

Comment: yes. case 1: list of id's limit 1 and case 2: count

Comment: @Premlatha, Not sure why you need only ids for age above 20 and only count below age 20
Anyway, this will give you what you expect.

`With CTE_above20 AS
( SELECT 'Ids of age above 20' ordr_id, id FROM students WHERE age > 20
), CTE_under20 AS
( SELECT 'Count from age below 20' ordr_id, CASE WHEN  (SELECT count(1) FROM CTE_above20 LIMIT 1) > 0 THEN NULL ELSE count(id) END as id 
 FROM students WHERE age < 20 )
SELECT * FROM CTE_above20
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM CTE_under20 
WHERE id is NOT  NULL`

Comment: I have tested this query. It works accordingly, thank you.

Comment: @Premlatha, made changes accordingly you can the answer below now.

Comment: @Premlatha If you would accept a comma-separated list of id's rather than multiple rows, this much easier query will do: `SELECT COALESCE(GROUP_CONCAT(IF(age > 20, id, NULL)), SUM(age < 20)) AS yourColumnName FROM students;` You could change that to rows in your application if necessary. Why do you ignore students who are exactly 20? Or is this a mistake?

Comment: ok @JonasMetzler , thanks. It is not mistake. My real time issue is different. not involving "<" or ">". I just want to know the approach to do if have 2 cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go;
As you asked for case 1: id age > 20 limit 1 and case 2: count of age < 20 only if there is no resultset from case 1.

This should work!!!

```
-- fetch some values
With CTE_above20 AS
(   SELECT 
        'Descending Top 1 id above 20' Description, id 
    FROM students WHERE age > 20 ORDER BY id desc limit 1 
), CTE_under20 AS
(   SELECT
        'Count of ids age below 20' Description
        , CASE WHEN  (SELECT count(1) FROM CTE_above20 LIMIT 1) > 0 THEN NULL ELSE count(id) END as id 
    FROM students WHERE age < 20 )
SELECT * FROM CTE_above20
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM CTE_under20 
WHERE id is NOT  NULL
```

Result 1: Insert statement with age > 20 and one for age < 20

```
-- insert some values
INSERT INTO students VALUES (1, 'Ryan', 'M',30);
INSERT INTO students VALUES (2, 'Joanna', 'F',40);
INSERT INTO students VALUES (3, 'Ryan', 'M',1);


 /*  Output 1
        Description                        Id
        --------------------------------------
        Descending Top 1 id above 20        2
        
*/
```

Result 2 All inserts which age  < 20

```
-- insert some values
INSERT INTO students VALUES (1, 'Ryan', 'M',10);
INSERT INTO students VALUES (2, 'Joanna', 'F',10);
INSERT INTO students VALUES (3, 'Ryan', 'M',1);

/*

Description                 Id
------------------------------
Count of ids age below 20   3
*/
```